# Setting New categorical variable values based on Timestamp in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with two columns **Date_Time** and **ENTRY**.
 **Date_Time** has hourly data captured for **2 months** and I need to fill **Entry** column values using logic in R.
 on below logic
 -> Entry should set to "FULL" only during **10 AM to 12 AM**& **2PM to 5PM**
 -> Entry should set to "EMPTY" **excluding** hours **10 AM to 12 AM**& **2PM to 5PM**

Snapshot of expected output

```
   **Date_Time**    **ENTRY**
    6/6/17 6:00 AM  EMPTY
    6/6/17 7:00 AM  EMPTY
    6/6/17 8:00 AM  EMPTY
    6/7/17 9:00 AM  EMPTY
    6/8/17 10:00 AM FULL
    6/9/17 11:00 AM FULL
    6/9/17 12:00 AM FULL
    6/9/2017 13:00 AM   EMPTY
    6/9/2017 14:00 AM   FULL
    6/9/2017 15:00 AM   FULL
    6/9/2017 16:00 AM   FULL
    6/9/2017 17:00 AM   FULL
    6/9/2017 18:00 AM   EMPTY
```

Comment: expected output shows `FULL` for 2AM to 5AM, when question ask for 2PM to 5PM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using `data.table` (assuming that your table is called `d`):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)
d[, AMPM := sapply(strsplit(Data_Time, " "), "[[", 3)]
d[, TIME := as.numeric(gsub(":.*", "", sapply(strsplit(Data_Time, " "), "[[", 2)))]
d[, ENTRY := "EMPTY"]
d[(AMPM == "AM" & TIME >= 10 & TIME <= 12) | 
  (AMPM == "PM" & TIME >= 2 & TIME <= 5), 
  ENTRY := "FULL"][, .(Data_Time, ENTRY)]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Solution is helpful, Will apply similar logic to get my problem statement solved